# Is there any other way to fill this array as needed

Tags: java, arrays

I want to fill an array with random integers but there is some restrictions

- every integer must be different from others
- these integers must be btw 354-4000

```
    package app;

    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    //import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class App {
        private static int flag_random,flag_same_chk;
        private static int[] array=new int[1000];

        //private static ArrayList<Integer> deleted_indexes= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        private static SecureRandom random=new SecureRandom();

        public static int[] number_generator(){
            int number=1+random.nextInt(4000);
            if(number<354){
                flag_random=1;
            }
            int[] random_status=new int[2];
            random_status[0]=flag_random;
            random_status[1]=number;
            return random_status;
        }
    //i for knowing the which index we are at & num for compare the sameness
        public static int is_same(int i,int num){
            for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
                if(array[k]==num){
                    flag_same_chk=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return flag_same_chk;
        }
        public static void fill_array(){
            for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
                int[] random_num=number_generator();
                int same_result=is_same(i, random_num[1]);
                if(random_num[0]==1 || same_result==1){
                    i--;
                    break;
                }else{
                    array[i]=random_num[1];
                    System.out.println(i);
                }   
            }
        }
        }
        public static void order_h_to_l(){
            int temp=0;
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
                    if(array[k]<array[i]){
                        temp=array[k];
                        array[k]=array[i];
                        array[i]=temp;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }    
        public static void order_l_to_h(){
            int temp=0;
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
                    if(array[k]>array[i]){
                        temp=array[k];
                        array[k]=array[i];
                        array[i]=temp;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            fill_array();
            print_array();

        }
        public static void print_array(){
            for(int i:array)
                System.out.print(i+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

I think there is problem with the fill array functions for loop. so lets focus on it; we are getting informations about random number(to be added) and is_same result. after the checking the results; if it cant be added to array then for loop breaks. is there any other way to make the restrictions successfully applied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int[] rand = new Random().ints()
                         .filter(i -> i >= 354 && i <= 4000) // only values in your range
                         .distinct()  // unique values
                         .limit(1000) // the number of values you want
                         .toArray();
```

@Amongalen's suggestion to restrict the random ints in the original range results in much faster performance, since you're not generating and skipping values outside of the desired range:

```
new Random().ints(354, 4001) // only generate values in the range (2nd arg is exclusive)
            .distinct()
            .limit(1000)
            .toArray();
```

Comment: Of course, it's really expressive, but not be really efficient. You might wait a long time for a random int to fall into the range. I'd rather use a supplier that seeds values as `threadSafeRandom.nextInt(rangeSize) + minValue`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simplier and more effective to just use `new Random().ints(354, 4000)...` instead of that additional filter?

Comment: @Amongalen : my though, with a better solution thanks.

Comment: there is always a better way. thanks. @Amongalen's solution way faster than bdkosher's

Comment: Since this is such a small number of values, I wonder what the efficiency would be of just filling a List with the values from 345 - 4000, shuffling the list, and then taking the first N values out.

Comment: @Jordan My thoughts exactly.  When I first saw this it was so intuitive to just shuffle the values. It's not as concise  but it's more efficient.

Comment: @jordan  The shuffle version runs about 4-5 times faster.  Unfortunately, it's not as "cool" as using streams.

Comment: @WJS I die a little inside every time someone posts a question of "How do I take this perfectly reasonable and easy-to-understand code, and refactor it use Streams?"  Don't get me wrong, I _like_ streams, but sometimes people just get blinded by "new and shiny".  Also, thanks for doing that benchmarking.  I assumed that shuffling would be faster, but that's a pretty significant difference!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very efficent way of doing it. Just allocate an array of integers and shuffle them.  No need to check for duplicates.

It works as follows:

1. Initialize an array with the desired range of values.
2. Allocate the solution array
3. Now generate a random value `n` between `0 and size`.
4. Add `v[n]` to result array.
5. Swap `v[size-1]` with `v[n]`
6. Decrement `size` and repeat.

By decrementing size, `v[n]` will never be used again because that value of `n` will never be generated again.

```
        int v[] = IntStream.rangeClosed(354,4000).toArray();
        int[] result = new int[1000];
        Random r = new Random();
        int size = v.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int n = r.nextInt(size);
            result[i] = v[n];
            int k = v[size-1];
            v[size-1] = v[n];
            v[n] = k;
            size--;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use hashset as the set has distinct elements. I've implemented a small code please go through it I think it solves the problem you mentioned.

```
    public static void main (String[] args) 
{
     int SET_SIZE_REQUIRED = 100;
     int LOW = 354;
     int HIGH = 4000;
        Random random = new Random();
        Set set = new HashSet<Integer>(SET_SIZE_REQUIRED);
        while(set.size()< SET_SIZE_REQUIRED) {
            while (set.add(random.nextInt(HIGH-LOW)+LOW) != true)
                ;
        }
        assert set.size() == SET_SIZE_REQUIRED;
        System.out.println(set);
}
```